# Can i bind my c++ code to lua and develop it to some lua game engine?

Tags: c++, binding, lua, love2d, moai

As the title says so i've been making some mini games from my early years in college but it's written in c++ i want to translate it to lua but not really expert with it, so i discovered how to bind the codes, can i bind it to lua and develop it to lua game engine like love2d and moai?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

There are rules you need to follow to get the function signature (C++ function to be called from Lua Script) right.

There are plenty of tutorials (e.g. [here](http://acamara.es/blog/2012/08/calling-c-functions-from-lua-5-2/) and [here](https://csl.name/post/lua-and-cpp/)) and [libraries](http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.2.1.tar.gz) that help you to do that.